# Named Entity Extraction

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to extract list of persons  using Stanford Named Entity Recognizer (NER) in Python NLTK. Code and obtained output is like this

**Code**

```
from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger
st = StanfordNERTagger('english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz')
sent = 'joel thompson  tracy k smith  new work world premierenew york philharmonic commission'
strin = sent.title()
value = st.tag(strin.split())
def get_continuous_chunks(tagged_sent):
    continuous_chunk = []
    current_chunk = []

    for token, tag in tagged_sent:
        if tag != "O":
            current_chunk.append((token, tag))
        else:
            if current_chunk: # if the current chunk is not empty
                continuous_chunk.append(current_chunk)
                current_chunk = []
    # Flush the final current_chunk into the continuous_chunk, if any.
    if current_chunk:
        continuous_chunk.append(current_chunk)
    return continuous_chunk

named_entities = get_continuous_chunks(value)
named_entities_str = [" ".join([token for token, tag in ne]) for ne in named_entities]
print(named_entities_str)
```

**Obtained Output**

```
[('Joel Thompson Tracy K Smith New Work World Premierenew York Philharmonic Commission',
  'PERSON')]
```

**Desired Output**

```
Person 1: Joel Thompson
Person 2: Tracy K Smith
Data : New Work World Premierenew York Philharmonic Commission
```

Comment: Did you try without converting the whole sentence to Title Case (i.e., without the statement ```strin = sent.title()```)?

Comment: in that case the names will not be recognized as names.